# Jasmine: Expected spy function to have been called but it was never called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

There are two functions `formatViews` and `test`.

Code:

```
const formatViews = (views) => {
    if(views >= 1000000) return `${(views / 1000000).toFixed(1)}M`;
    if(views >= 1000) return `${(views / 1000).toFixed(1)}K`;
    return views.toString();
};

const test = () => {
    console.log(formatViews(10000000));
}
```

I have tried to write an unit test case using Jasmine and karma.

Code:

```
describe('test', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        window.formatViews = formatViews;
    });
    it('should test', () => {
        const formatViewsSpy = spyOn(window, 'formatViews').and.callThrough();
        test();
        console.log(formatViewsSpy.calls.all());
        expect(formatViewsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10000000);
    })
});
```

But the test case failed by saying:

```
LOG: []
test should test FAILED
        Expected spy formatViews to have been called with:
          [ 10000000 ]
        but it was never called.
```

My jasmine config:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.?(m)js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "*.?(m)js"
  ],
  "env": {
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": true
  }
}
```

Not sure about the helpers but generally all my `js` files are directly inside outer directory.

Not sure what to do, tried all solutions, but none worked. Please help me in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to test the "test" function, which in turn calls the formatViews function. However, it seems that the spy on formatViews is not being triggered.

One issue in your code could be that you are assigning window.formatViews = formatViews in the beforeAll block. Instead try to assign it with beforeEach(), like this:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        window.formatViews = formatViews;
    });

    it('should test', () => {
        const formatViewsSpy = spyOn(window, 'formatViews').and.callThrough();
        test();
        console.log(formatViewsSpy.calls.all());
        expect(formatViewsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10000000);
    })
});
```

This should ensure that the spy is properly set up before calling the test function.

Comment: the code didn't work